# How to change the device orientation programmatically and screen's rotation direction should be in clock wise direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

I want to rotate screen forcefully on click of buttons. I have two buttons one for Rotate the screen in **clock wise direction** and other one to rotate in **anti clock wise direction**.

My code is- 
1)`[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"]`
For anti clock wise rotation and its working fine.

2) `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight] forKey:@"orientation"]`
For clock wise rotation. This code also rotate screen in anti clock wise direction. I am excepting clock wise direction rotation.

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each orientation in iOS has a raw value.

1. portrait = 1
2. portraitUpsideDown = 2
3. landscapeLeft = 3
4. landscapeRight = 4

You can change orientation based on these values.

Here is how I have done it in **swift**

1. Rotate in clockwise direction:

   ```
   @IBAction func rotateClockwise(_ sender: Any) {


   let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
   print("Current state:",orientation.rawValue)
   var newOrientation: Int {
       switch orientation.rawValue {
       case 1:
           return 3
       case 2:
           return 4
       case 3:
           return 2
       case 4:
           return 1
       default:
           return 1
       }
   }


   UIDevice.current.setValue(newOrientation, forKey: "orientation")
   ```

   }
2. Rotate in anti clockwise direction:

   ```
   @IBAction func rotateAntiClockwise(_ sender: Any) {

   let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
   print("Current state:",orientation.rawValue)
   var newOrientation: Int {
       switch orientation.rawValue {
       case 1:
           return 4
       case 2:
           return 3
       case 3:
           return 1
       case 4:
           return 2
       default:
           return 1
       }
   }


   UIDevice.current.setValue(newOrientation, forKey: "orientation")
   }
   ```

**Note**

Make sure to select [all orientations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9h0l.png) in target - general

If that doesn't work add the following code to view controller class

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get { return .all } }
```

Comment: Your functions return exactly the same values.

Comment: UIDevice.current.orientation returns current orientation value. Based on that and tapped button we determine next orientation.

Comment: Yes, but both functions looks identical.